# How to document function parameters while commenting in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, function, parameters, comments, documentation

I would like to make some functions in Flutter, and to comment functions and parameters.
I was doing it earlyer in C#, but don't know how to document parameters in Flutter.
For example, I want to document function with parameter

```
  /// Returns a number from a string.
  int stringToInt(String textString) {
    return int.parse(textString);
    }
```

How to comment parameter textString, for example /// a String contains numbers.

Best regards,
Darko

Answer (score 3):

Flutter uses Dart's comments ([link to documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#doc-comments))

Documentation comments start with a triple slash `///`, from the docs:

> For historical reasons, dart doc supports two syntaxes of doc comments: /// (“C# style”) and /** ... */ (“JavaDoc style”). We prefer /// because it’s
> more compact. /** and */ add two content-free lines to a multiline doc
> comment. The /// syntax is also easier to read in some situations, such as
> when a doc comment contains a bulleted list that uses * to mark list items.

If you want to refer to any method or variable you use square brackets `[]` ([reference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#do-use-square-brackets-in-doc-comments-to-refer-to-in-scope-identifiers))

Dart does not use comments to explain parameters, exceptions, and such ([reference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#do-use-prose-to-explain-parameters-return-values-and-exceptions))

> Other languages use verbose tags and sections to describe what the parameters and returns of a method are. [...] The convention in Dart is to integrate that into the description of the method
> and highlight parameters using square brackets.

Read the complete documentation for all the other details and conventions.